# Returning a string error message to user instead of BadRequest inside a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following code you see below.

If the file that the user uploads is not of a certain file extension or the file is too big, then I want the controller to return an error message to the user.

Right now, I just return a generic bad request.

Is there a way to have the controller reject the upload while also showing the appropriate error message to the user in the browser?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadUserFiles([FromForm] IFormFile gamerFile)
    {
        int maxFileSize = 52428800; //50MB
        var allowedExtensions = new[] { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif", ".bmp", ".pdf", ".odt", ".doc", ".docx", ".xls", ".xlsx", ".ppt", ".pptx", ".rtf", ".txt" };

        if(gamerFile.Length > maxFileSize)
        {
            return BadRequest();
            // return an error to user saying max file size exceeded
        }

        if(!allowedExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(gamerFile.FileName)))
        {
            return BadRequest();
            // return an error to user saying the file was not a valid type
        }

        var filePath = Path.Combine(@"R:\gamer\screens\uploadedMediaFiles", gamerFile.FileName);

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await gamerFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }
        return Ok();

    }
```

Comment: You do realise that you can do `return BadRequest("Reason the request failed")`? See the docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.badrequest?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return BadRequest("Message")
```

You can add the string as the argument to `BadRequest` method.

Comment: Oh wow I didn't know that.  So you can just do return BadRequest("You file was too big.") ? And the user will see that?

Comment: User will see response content "Your file was too big."... and StatusCode will be 400